# Debugging old Fortran code for sediment dynamics

Tags: fortran

I am looking at some Fortran code from an old scanned paper. The scan quality is not great so I may have copied it wrong. I tried to run this using an online Fortran compiler but it bombs out. Not being familiar with Fortran, I was wondering if someone can point out where the syntax does not make sense? The code is from a paper on sediment dynamics:

Komar, P.D. and Miller, M.C., 1975. On the comparison between the threshold of sediment motion under waves and unidirectional currents with a discussion of the practical evaluation of the threshold: Reply. Journal of Sedimentary Research, 45(1).

```
PROGRAM TSHOLD 
REAL LI, LO
G = 981.0 
PIE = 3.1416 
RHOW  = 1.00 
READ (6O,1) DIAM, RHOS
1 FORMAT (2X, F6.3,2X, F5.3) 
IF(DIAM .LT. 0.05) GO TO 5 
A = 0.463 * PIE 
B = 0.25 
GO TO 7 
5 A = 0.21 
B = 0.50 
7 PWR = 1.0 / (2.0 - B) 
FAC = (A * (RHOS - RHOW) * G/(RHOW * PIE**B))**PWR
FAC1 = FAC * DIAM**((1.0 - B) * PWR) 
T = 1.0 
15 J = 1.20 
LD = 156.13 * (T**2) 
UM = FAC1 * T**(B*PWR) 
WRITE(61,9) DIAM, T, UM
9 FORMAT(1H0, 10X, 17HGRAIN DIAMETER = ,F6.3,1X,2HCM //
1 11X, 14HWAVE PERIOD = ,F5.2, 1X, 3HSEC // 
2 11X, 22HORBITAL VELOCITY, UM = ,F6.2, 1X, 6HCM/SECl //
3 20X, 6HHEIGHT, 5X, 5HDEPTH, 8X, 3HH/L, 6X, 7HH/DEPTH //
4 22X, 2HCM, 8X, 2HCM /)
C INCREMENT WAVE HEIGHT, CALCULATE DEPTH 
H = 10.0 
DO 12 K = 1.60
SING = PIE * H / (UM * T) 
X = SING 
IF(X.LT.1.0) GO TO 30 
30 ASINH = X - 0.16666*X**3.0 + 0.07500* X ** 5.0 - 0.04464 * X ** 7.0
1 + 0.03038 * X ** 9.0 - 0.02237 * X ** 11.0 
32 LI = LD * (SINH(ASINH)/COSH(ASINH)) 
OPTH = ASINH * LI / 6.2832 
C CHECK WAVE STABILITY 
RATIO = H / DPTH 
IF(RATIO.GE.0.78) GO TO 11 
STEEP = H / LI 
TEST = 0.142 * (SINH(ASINH)/COSH(ASINH)) 
IF(STEEP.GE.TEST) GO TO 11 
WRITE(61,10) H, OPTH, STEEP, RATIO 
I0 FORMAT(IH0, 20X, F5.1, 4X, E9.3, 4X, F5.3, 4X, F4.2) 
11 H = H + 10.0 
12 CONTINUE 
T = T + 1.0 
15 CONTINUE 
END
```

Comment: "Bombs out" is not very useful - please tell us exactly what the error message is, and also the exact command you used to compile it.

Comment: This is exceptionally far from being valid Fortran code from 1975. Having a "P" (for example) in the first column of source code was not allowed until Fortran 90.

Comment: Since you don't have a single, specific question, I think Fortran Discourse may be a better place to post.

Comment: https://fortran-lang.discourse.group/ is the place to ask for more help.

Comment: Interesting to see a Taylor approximation to `ASINH`.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is more likely that old Fortran requires fixed form code formatting where the number of spaces before a statement *is very important*.

Here are some general rules

- Normal statements start at column 7 and beyond
- Lines cannot exceed 72 columns
- Any character placed on column 6 indicates the line is a continuation from the line above. I see that on the code above in the lines following `9 FORMAT(..`
- A number placed between columns 1-5 indicates a label, which can be a target of a `GO TO` statement, a `DO` statement or a formatting specification.
- The character `C` on the first column, and sometimes any character on the first column indicate the line is a comment line.

see [https://people.cs.vt.edu/~asandu/Courses/MTU/CS2911/fortran_notes/node4.html](https://people.cs.vt.edu/%7Easandu/Courses/MTU/CS2911/fortran_notes/node4.html) for more info.

Based on the rules above, here is how to enter the code, with the correct spacing. I run the F77 code through a converter to make it compatible with F90 and F77 at the same time. The code below **might** compile with the online compiler now.

```
      PROGRAM TSHOLD 
      REAL LI, LO 
      G = 981.0 
      PIE = 3.1416 
      RHOW  = 1.00 
      READ (60,1) DIAM, RHOS 
    1 FORMAT (2X, F6.3,2X, F5.3) 
      IF(DIAM .LT. 0.05) GO TO 5 
      A = 0.463 * PIE 
      B = 0.25 
      GO TO 7 
    5 A = 0.21 
      B = 0.50 
    7 PWR = 1.0 / (2.0 - B) 
      FAC = (A * (RHOS - RHOW) * G/(RHOW * PIE**B))**PWR 
      FAC1 = FAC * DIAM**((1.0 - B) * PWR) 
      T = 1.0 
     DO 15 J=1,20 
      LD = 156.13 * (T**2) 
      UM = FAC1 * T**(B*PWR) 
      WRITE(61,9) DIAM, T, UM 
    9 FORMAT(1H0, 10X, 17HGRAIN DIAMETER = ,F6.3,1X,2HCM //             &
     & 11X, 14HWAVE PERIOD = ,F5.2, 1X, 3HSEC //                        &
     & 11X, 22HORBITAL VELOCITY, UM = ,F6.2, 1X, 6HCM/SECl //           &
     & 20X, 6HHEIGHT, 5X, 5HDEPTH, 8X, 3HH/L, 6X, 7HH/DEPTH //          &
     & 22X, 2HCM, 8X, 2HCM /)                                           
! INCREMENT WAVE HEIGHT, CALCULATE DEPTH                                
      H = 10.0 
      DO 12 K = 1,60 
      SING = PIE * H / (UM * T) 
      X = SING 
      IF(X.LT.1.0) GO TO 30 
   30 ASINH = X - 0.16666*X**3.0 + 0.07500* X ** 5.0 - 0.04464 * X ** 7.&
     & + 0.03038 * X ** 9.0 - 0.02237 * X ** 11.0                       
   32 LI = LD * (SINH(ASINH)/COSH(ASINH)) 
      OPTH = ASINH * LI / 6.2832 
! CHECK WAVE STABILITY                                                  
      RATIO = H / DPTH 
      IF(RATIO.GE.0.78) GO TO 11 
      STEEP = H / LI 
      TEST = 0.142 * (SINH(ASINH)/COSH(ASINH)) 
      IF(STEEP.GE.TEST) GO TO 11 
      WRITE(61,10) H, OPTH, STEEP, RATIO 
   10 FORMAT(G14.4, 20X, F5.1, 4X, E9.3, 4X, F5.3, 4X, F4.2) 
   11 H = H + 10.0 
   12 CONTINUE 
      T = T + 1.0 
   15 CONTINUE 
      END
```

I found several transcription errors, replacing commas with dots, zeros with the letter O, and a missing `DO` statement.

Comment: I was able to compile the above code, both locally and online. See https://onlinegdb.com/EPG3SPBK6 . Note that it requires an input file named `fort.60` with two numbers for the variables `DIAM, RHOS`. The output is presented in a file named `fort.61`