# How to write long string variables in Fortran 77

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I am trying to create a string variable of 231 characters in Fortran 77. Such a string would not fit within the 72 columns per line limit in Fortran 77. This would not compile:

```
      CHARACTER*256 MYSTRING
      DATA MYSTRING / 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.' /
```

How do I split the string over multiples lines in the source code?

Comment: Many of the answers in the linked question focus on continuation in free-form source, but continuation in fixed form is also covered.

Comment: Line continuation is  done by placing any character on column 6 for each subsequent line.

Comment: @francescalus I still don't know the answer. I have read the answers to that question at least 5 times. I will ask again, but with more detail. Examples for my specific case would really help, since I am new to Fortran 77 and Fortran in general.

Comment: Continue your fixed-form source line like you would any other line. If you aren't sure how to continue lines in general, we can find explanations of that. Although it isn't a DATA statement, I show string continuation in fixed-form in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47375423/3157076) to that question (second part from the end).

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69677918/13813219) to another question, and notice the line continuation on the lines that start with `&`.  It is important to be placed exactly on column 6.

Comment: Note this is not specific to Fortran77. It is specific to fixed form Fortran, which specifies how the code is laid out in the file, not what the code actually is. Nobody should be teaching or writing in Fortran77 nowadays, but there might be reason to use the old, fixed format.

Comment: I've posted a new question: [Is it necessary to place an ampersand on the 73rd column for line continuations in Fortran 77?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70074833/is-it-necessary-to-place-an-ampersand-on-the-73rd-column-for-line-continuations)