# Is it necessary to place an ampersand on the 73rd column for line continuations in Fortran 77?

Tags: fortran, fortran77

Consider the following code which has a long string variable:

```
      CHARACTER*256 MYSTRING
      DATA MYSTRING / 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscin&
     &g elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna&
     & aliqua.' /
      PRINT *, MYSTRING
```

In column 73 of lines 2 and 3, there is an ampersand. Are the ampersands necessary, or can they be removed? I understand that the beginning `&` on column 6 is important for line continuations, but I do not know whether or not the trailing `&` on column 73 has any significance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not necessary in *fixed source form* (not just Fortran 77). Characters in columns 73 and further are ignored.

But the ampersand are useful when the same source file is compiled as *free source form*, for example as an include file that is compatible with both forms (*"intersection form"*).